# How to use ODBC on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

Is there ODBC Driver on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Officially, AgensGraph does not support ODBC Driver.

But, ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL is compatible partially.

You can download source code of ODBC Drivser on "http://odbc.postgresql.org".

After download source, Run procedures on follow.

```
$ tar xzf psqlodbc-*.tar.gz 
$ cd psqlodbc-*
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After Driver installed, You must register AgensGraph on "odic.ini".

```
$ cat >$HOME/.odbc.ini <<EOF
[agensgraph]
Description = ODBC for AgensGraph
Server      = localhost
Port        = 5432
Database    = $USER
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup       = /usr/local/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64    = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
Setup64     = /usr/local/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage   = 1
EOF
```

You can test ODBC connection using "isql" command.

```
$ isql agensgraph
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```